# Does QWebSocketServer support path parsing?

Tags: websocket, qt5

I feel that Qt's WebSocket implementation does not care about what path you send to connect to the server, so that there is no distinguishing between, say:

`ws://localhost:1234/chatroom`

and

`ws://localhost:1234/echotest`

Is this (URI path parsing) supported by QWebSocketServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found it is, but not via a direct API call.
When a connection is established, we are able to obtain the URL of the request, by `socket->requestUrl()`, then we can respond according to what url the request sent.